# Select worksheet using combo box and display the data in the listbox

Tags: select, combobox, listbox, worksheet

I have Entry Form in excel VBA ( For example employee information First name , Last name , Job Title , Hiring date,..etc) and save this information in worksheet called Database.

What's the easiest way that I can add combobox and add another two new sheets (sheet1 name: Database 2020 and sheet2 name : Database 2019) and Add the new combobox to the Entry Form once I run the micro I can Select from the combobox Database 2020 or Database 2019 then it will display the information for the selected sheet in the listbox that I have in the Entry Form and I can edit it and delete from that sheet and save the information

Right now I have only one worksheet named Database when I run the micro will display what I have employee information in that sheet in the listbox and I can add new employee information or edit exist employee information then save it, for now I need to use two separate sheets instead of one worksheet.

Thank you,

Anyone can help ?